# Algorithm for Creating 2x2 Tables to Demonstrate Simpson's Paradox

Tags: simpsons-paradox, constrained-optimization, integer-programming

Suppose I have a 2x2 table: $T = \lbrace a,b,c,d \rbrace$, where $a=T(1,1), b=T(2,1), c=T(1,2), d=T(2,2)$, where all entries of $T$ are positive integers. Let us assume that $\frac{ad}{bc} > 1$.

Now, I would like to create tables $T_1 = \lbrace a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1 \rbrace$ and $T_2 = \lbrace a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2 \rbrace$ subject to following equality and inequality constraints:
$$a_1 + a_2 = a;$$ $$b_1 + b_2 = b;$$ $$c_1 + c_2 = c;$$ $$d_1 + d_2 = d,$$ and further, $$\frac{a_1d_1}{b_1c_1} < 1; \frac{a_2d_2}{b_2c_2} < 1$$.

This problem is to demonstrate the Simpson's paradox where there is a reversal in the association between row and column variables in a 2x2 table.  Is there an algorithmic approach to creating tables $T_1$ and $T_2$ given $T$ and the constraints?  Of course, there could be no feasible solution, which the algorithm should declare. Then, there could also be multiple solutions.  In such case, can we create the two 2x2 tables which demonstrate the most extreme reversal of the odds ratio?

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://online.stat.psu.edu/onlinecourses/sites/stat504/files/lesson05/slavfienPistone2009.pdf

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at the paper.

Answer (score 1):

For small entries of $T$ (e.g., all less than $10$), it would be feasible to enumerate all $(a−1)(b−1)(c−1)(d−1)$ possibilities (disregarding the inherent symmetry between $T_1$ and $T_2$ for simplicity), plot $\frac{a_1d_1}{b_1c_1}$ against $\frac{a_2d_2}{b_2c_2}$, calculate the convex hull and extract the points in the bottom left quadrant of the convex hull, which would be Pareto optimal for your request.

For instance, if we have $a=10$, $b=8$, $c=7$ and $d=9$, then we have $9\times7\times 6\times 8=3024$ different possibilities. Of these, $24$ satisfy $\frac{a_1d_1}{b_1c_1}<1$ and $\frac{a_2d_2}{b_2c_2}<1$, and the following entries for $T1$ and $T_2$ are Pareto optimal:

```
 a1 b1 c1 d1 a2 b2 c2 d2 a1d1.div.b1c1 a2d2.div.b2c2
  1  3  3  8  9  5  4  1     0.8888889     0.4500000
  9  4  3  1  1  4  4  8     0.7500000     0.5000000
  1  4  3  8  9  4  4  1     0.6666667     0.5625000
  9  4  4  1  1  4  3  8     0.5625000     0.6666667
  1  4  4  8  9  4  3  1     0.5000000     0.7500000
  9  5  4  1  1  3  3  8     0.4500000     0.8888889
```

The two middle rows are perhaps the most interesting. Up to symmetry, we are looking at

$$ a_1 = 1, \quad b_1\approx\frac{b}{2}, \quad c_1\approx\frac{c}{2}, \quad d_1 = d-1. $$

Playing around with other values of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ yields similar results. It looks like your best bet would be to look at these and check whether rounding up or down in the case of odd $b$ and $c$ yields nicer results for your taste - they both seem to be Pareto optimal in any case. It might be possible to prove some kind of optimality for these settings.

[image: valid combinations]

R code:

```
aa <- 10; dd <- 9; bb <- 8; cc <- 7 # ensure ad/bc>1
combinations <- expand.grid(list(1:(aa-1),1:(bb-1),1:(cc-1),1:(dd-1)))
names(combinations) <- c("a1","b1","c1","d1")

combinations$a2 <- aa-combinations$a1
combinations$b2 <- bb-combinations$b1
combinations$c2 <- cc-combinations$c1
combinations$d2 <- dd-combinations$d1

combinations$a1d1.div.b1c1 <- with(combinations,(a1*d1)/(b1*c1))
combinations$a2d2.div.b2c2 <- with(combinations,(a2*d2)/(b2*c2))

combinations_OK <- subset(combinations,a1d1.div.b1c1<1 & a2d2.div.b2c2<1)

hull <- with(combinations_OK,chull(a1d1.div.b1c1,a2d2.div.b2c2))
leftmost_index <- which.min(combinations_OK$a1d1.div.b1c1)
bottom_index <- which.min(combinations_OK$a2d2.div.b2c2)
leftmost_point <- unlist(combinations_OK[leftmost_index,c("a1d1.div.b1c1","a2d2.div.b2c2")])
bottom_point <- unlist(combinations_OK[bottom_index,c("a1d1.div.b1c1","a2d2.div.b2c2")])

pareto_optimal <- hull[combinations_OK[hull,"a1d1.div.b1c1"]<=bottom_point["a1d1.div.b1c1"] &
    combinations_OK[hull,"a2d2.div.b2c2"]<=leftmost_point["a2d2.div.b2c2"]]

with(combinations_OK, plot(a1d1.div.b1c1,a2d2.div.b2c2,las=1,pch=19,cex=0.8,
    xlab=expression(a[1]*d[1]/b[1]*c[1]),   ylab=expression(a[2]*d[2]/b[2]*c[2])))
with(combinations_OK[pareto_optimal,], lines(a1d1.div.b1c1,a2d2.div.b2c2,type="o",col="red",cex=1.2))

nrow(combinations)
nrow(combinations_OK)
print(combinations_OK[pareto_optimal,],row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: @Kolassa:  thank you.  It would be nice if this approach can be extend to larger tables.  I wrote a code based on exhaustive search to find the optimal table.  It works for cells on the order of 100.  It appears to confirm your proposal that: $a_1 = 1, \quad b_1 = \frac{b}{2}, \quad c_1 = \frac{c}{2}, \quad d_1 = d-1$